# Postgres Migration Issue 9.0.0 to 9.3, collation error

Tags: database, postgresql, migration, collation

I was trying to migrate from PostgreSQL data from PostgreSQL 9.0.0 to 9.3. I am having an issue related to the collation.

`ERROR: could not determine which collation to use for string comparison
  Hint: Use the COLLATE clause to set the collation explicitly.`

I have done quite a research and found that it has an issue in pre-9.1 we have "citext" and in post-9.1 we have to add the extension. [if I understood correctly].

Here what I have done so far :

- Taken the dump from 9.0.0 database.
- Installed the instance 9.3.1 in another instance.
- Created a database there and run the following query to add the extension `CREATE EXTENSION citext`. Till here I do not have problem.
- While importing the dump from 9.0 after executing the query, I am getting a error, as extension "citext" already exists.

I am not sure if i have done the correct steps in resolving the problem. As per mu understanding, in post 9.1 postgres, we do not have "citext" extension so we manually adding the extension by running the query. So now why it is trying to add the "citext" extension "create citext;" to add citext.

Please correct me if i am leading in a wrong direction.

Thanks
Sovan

Comment: Restore the dump, then `CREATE EXTENSION citext FROM UNPACKAGED`.

Comment: I have used that Query as well after restoring the dump, but I am getting another issue

`ERROR:  cannot cast type oid[] to oidvector`